# VBA on Apple Mac: Runtime Error 380

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying run a VBA macro on an Apple MAC but I am getting A

> Runtime error 380

at the following line (second line displayed - the first to show how the Range name is identified)

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyGraphics", RefersToR1C1:=Range(Sheets("Graphics").Range("Graphics_Files").Offset(1, 0), Sheets("Graphics").Range("Graphics_Files").Offset(1000, 0).End(xlUp))
    GraphicsForm.LBoxImage.RowSource = "MyGraphics"
```

The macro runs perfectly on Windows.

Comment: COuld you add a bit more of your code? The part defining `GraphicsForm.LBoxImage` could be useful

Comment: Maybe try `GraphicsForm.LBoxImage.RowSource = Range("MyGraphics").Parent.Name & "!" & Range("MyGraphics").Address`

Comment: The code provided produces a Run-time error '380': Could not set the RowSource property. Invalid property value.

Comment: So what are `GraphicsForm` and `LBoxImage`??

Comment: GraphicsForm is the name of the Form being used and LBoxImage is a ListBox. Somethiing else has cropped up since I started looking at this problem. The Office version on the MAC updated and now when I get a run-time error (or any error) and click on Debug the project code does not open. I have to manually go to VBA on the MAC and select the module which seems to reset the debug mode or something as no error is indicated.

Comment: Is it a UserForm? What is LBoxImage?